# elfinder error when go back to ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, elfinder

I use the latest CKEditor with latest elfinder
When i click twice on the image to go back ckeditor, I have this error

Error in `getFileCallback`.
elf is not defined

my main.cke.js

```
"use strict";

(function(){
    var // jQuery and jQueryUI version
        jqver = '3.2.1',
        uiver = '1.12.1',

        // Detect language (optional)
        lang = (function() {
            var locq = window.location.search,
                fullLang, locm, lang;
            if (locq && (locm = locq.match(/lang=([a-zA-Z_-]+)/))) {
                // detection by url query (?lang=xx)
                fullLang = locm[1];
            } else {
                // detection by browser language
                fullLang = (navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage);
            }
            lang = fullLang.substr(0,2);
            if (lang === 'ja') lang = 'jp';
            else if (lang === 'pt') lang = 'pt_BR';
            else if (lang === 'ug') lang = 'ug_CN';
            else if (lang === 'zh') lang = (fullLang.substr(0,5).toLowerCase() === 'zh-tw')? 'zh_TW' : 'zh_CN';
            return lang;
        })(),

        // Start elFinder (REQUIRED)
        start = function(elFinder, editors, config) {
            // load jQueryUI CSS
            elFinder.prototype.loadCss('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/'+uiver+'/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

            $(function() {
                var optEditors = {
                        commandsOptions: {
                            edit: {
                                editors: Array.isArray(editors)? editors : []
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    opts = {

       getFileCallback : function(file) {
         window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction((function() {
           var reParam = new RegExp('(?:[\?&]|&amp;)CKEditorFuncNum=([^&]+)', 'i') ;
           var match = window.location.search.match(reParam) ;
           return (match && match.length > 1) ? match[1] : '' ;
         })(), file.url);
         elf.destroy();
         window.close();
       },
       url : 'php/connector.minimal.php', // connector URL (REQUIRED)
       lang: lang

     };

                // Interpretation of "elFinderConfig"
                if (config && config.managers) {
                    $.each(config.managers, function(id, mOpts) {
                        opts = Object.assign(opts, config.defaultOpts || {});
                        // editors marges to opts.commandOptions.edit
                        try {
                            mOpts.commandsOptions.edit.editors = mOpts.commandsOptions.edit.editors.concat(editors || []);
                        } catch(e) {
                            Object.assign(mOpts, optEditors);
                        }
                        // Make elFinder
                        $('#' + id).elfinder(
                            // 1st Arg - options
                            $.extend(true, { lang: lang }, opts, mOpts || {}),
                            // 2nd Arg - before boot up function
                            function(fm, extraObj) {
                                // `init` event callback function
                                fm.bind('init', function() {
                                    // Optional for Japanese decoder "extras/encoding-japanese.min"
                                    delete fm.options.rawStringDecoder;
                                    if (fm.lang === 'jp') {
                                        require(
                                            [ 'extras/encoding-japanese.min' ],
                                            function(Encoding) {
                                                if (Encoding.convert) {
                                                    fm.options.rawStringDecoder = function(s) {
                                                        return Encoding.convert(s,{to:'UNICODE',type:'string'});
                                                    };
                                                }
                                            }
                                        );
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        );
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('"elFinderConfig" object is wrong.');
                }
            });
        },

        // JavaScript loader (REQUIRED)
        load = function() {
            require(
                [
                    'elfinder'
                    , 'extras/editors.default.min'               // load text, image editors
                    , 'elFinderConfig'
                //  , 'extras/quicklook.googledocs.min'          // optional preview for GoogleApps contents on the GoogleDrive volume
                ],
                start,
                function(error) {
                    alert(error.message);
                }
            );
        },

        // is IE8? for determine the jQuery version to use (optional)
        ie8 = (typeof window.addEventListener === 'undefined' && typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined');

    // config of RequireJS (REQUIRED)
    require.config({
        baseUrl : 'js',
        paths : {
            'jquery'   : '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/'+(ie8? '1.12.4' : jqver)+'/jquery.min',
            'jquery-ui': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/'+uiver+'/jquery-ui.min',
            'elfinder' : 'elfinder.min'
        },
        waitSeconds : 10 // optional
    });

    // check elFinderConfig and fallback
    if (! require.defined('elFinderConfig')) {
        define('elFinderConfig', {
            // elFinder options (REQUIRED)
            // Documentation for client options:
            // https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-configuration-options
            defaultOpts : {
                url : 'php/connector.minimal.php' // connector URL (REQUIRED)
                ,commandsOptions : {
                    edit : {
                        extraOptions : {
                            // set API key to enable Creative Cloud image editor
                            // see https://console.adobe.io/
                            creativeCloudApiKey : '',
                            // browsing manager URL for CKEditor, TinyMCE
                            // uses self location with the empty value
                            managerUrl : ''
                        }
                    }
                    ,quicklook : {
                        // to enable preview with Google Docs Viewer
                        googleDocsMimes : ['application/pdf', 'image/tiff', 'application/vnd.ms-office', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-word', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation']
                    }
                }
            },
            managers : {
                'elfinder': {},
            }
        });
    }

    // load JavaScripts (REQUIRED)
    load();

})();
```

Comment: I noticed the mistake of elFinder Wiki. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getFileCallback : function(file) {
```

to

```
getFileCallback : function(file, elf) {
```